# Geometry column: STGeomFromText and SRID (what is an SRID?)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, geometry

I'm playing with the new geography column in SQL Server 2008 and the STGeomFromText function.  Here is my code (works with AdventureWorks2008)

```
DECLARE @region geography;
set @region = geography::STGeomFromText('POLYGON((
        -80.0 50.0, -90.0 50.0,
        -90.0 25.0, -80.0 25.0,
        -80.0 50.0))', 4326);

SELECT @region;
```

My question is about the 4326 in the code.  It is supposed to be a spacial Reference ID.  When I go to MSDN there isn't a lot on it.  If I change the value to 56 I get an error telling me the value must be in the sys.spatial_reference_systems table.

You can look at that table by executing:

```
select * from sys.spatial_reference_systems
```

There is a well_known_text column in that table, but it doesn't tell me much.  The value for 4326 is:

```
GEOGCS["WGS 84", DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984", ELLIPSOID["WGS 84", 6378137, 298.257223563]], PRIMEM["Greenwich", 0], UNIT["Degree", 0.0174532925199433]]
```

Can anyone explain this mystery to me?  What is the SRID?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

So I ended up talking with an ex-military guy yesterday who was a radar/mapping specialist.
Basically, he knew exactly what that number (4326) was, where it came from, and why it is there.

It is an industry standard for computing geography.  The problem is that the earth is not a perfect sphere (it bulges in the middle), and SRID 4326 accounts for that.

As I stated, the table sys.spatial_reference_systems lists all of the code and what they are.  But the short version is that you are really only going to use 4326 unless you have a very specific reason to use something different.

Comment: I disagree with your statement "You're really only going to use 4326 unless you have a very specific reason."  Any time you're dealing with data in a small area (think state or county as opposed to the world) you're going to use a local, projected coordinate system.  These systems are designed to better represent the earth's surface on a 2D plane as opposed to the 3D globe.  More often than not you'll wind up getting data in a projection other than WGS84, and you'll need to convert.

If you're only dealing with GPS points then you're correct in assuming the data are in 4326 99% of the time.

Answer (score 17):

[SRID = Spatial Reference IDentifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRID)

coordinates must use the same SRID to be comparable. otherwise you'd end up comparing kilometeres and miles. or something similar.

Answer (score 17):

There are a lot of systems to map the earth. For example you want to map some state in USA. You can set the most south-east point as 0,0 and map all other spatial coordinates according to this point. On the other hand you may want to map some spatial data that span all over the map. In any case you must choose some point as 0,0. In addition you must select some sort of measurement unit: miles/kilometers/degrees/some other magical unit that suits you better. Over the years a lot of such systems where developed. Each has its own zero point, its own coordinates, its own rules about if the earth is flat or not. SRID or SRS is the id of such system. Using this id you can map point expressed in one system to another system, although sometimes it involves some pretty complex math.

And about 4326 SRID. It also called "WGS 84" 
(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Geodetic_System) system. It's the most common system to represent point on spherical(not flat) earth. It uses degree,minute,second notation and its x and y coordinates are usually called latitude and longitude.

Most used non-spherical earth projection is called UTM. You can read about it here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Transverse_Mercator_coordinate_system

Anyway, as long you are not doing any spatial conversions from one system to other, you don't really care about the system that you data uses.

Comment: That last line really bugs me, promoting ignorance because *it probably doesn't matter*?

Answer (score 2):

I have found this website: http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/4326/ quite helpful in understanding the SRID you intend to use. It provides a handy map, some bounding box information and other links.

For other SRIDs simply change the digits at the end of the URL to what you are after.

Answer (score 1):

The distance returned depends on the ["Spatial Reference Identifier (SRID)"](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb964707.aspx) you define for your geography types.

In the example below, the default [SRID](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb964707.aspx) of 4336 is used, see the second argument of [STGeomFromText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933823.aspx). This means the distance returned is in meters, you find this via querying the catalog view [spatial_reference_systems](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb964707.aspx) i.e. `select srs.unit_of_measure from sys.spatial_reference_systems as srs where srs.spatial_reference_id = 4326`

As an alternative to [STGeomFromText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933823.aspx), you can use [parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933824.aspx) which assumes a [SRID](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb964707.aspx) of 4326 and you don't have to specify one explicitly.

When calculating the distance between two points, you must use the same [SRID](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb964707.aspx) for both geography types else you get an error. Example:

```
DECLARE @address1 GEOGRAPHY
DECLARE @address2 GEOGRAPHY
DECLARE @distance float
SET @address1 = GEOGRAPHY::STGeomFromText ('point(53.046908 -2.991673)',4326)
SET @address2 = GEOGRAPHY::STGeomFromText ('point(51.500152 -0.126236)',4326)
SET @distance = @address1.STDistance(@address2)
SELECT @distance --this is the distance in meters
```