# How to import Lat/Long data into PostgreSQL

Tags: django, postgresql, postgis, geodjango

PostgreSQL / Django / newbie here.

I've got a bunch of JSON data with venues and lat/long information, and I'm looking to import it into my database. So far I've fenagled a script to format my JSON into SQL statements, so I can import them with a slew of INSERT statements.

But my 'location' field (a PointField) is giving me grief when I try to use ST_PointFromText('POINT(lon lat)') syntax. Specifically:

ERROR:  new row for relation "finder_venue" violates check constraint "enforce_srid_location"

So how do I generate a proper SRID?

Or, given Django's ease, I can't help but feel like I'm committing programmatic heresy here. Can someone point me in a more intelligent direction?

Thanks,

Jon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set the SRID in PostGIS, you can do this:

```
ST_SetSRID(ST_PointFromText('POINT(-122 37)'), 4326)
```

(4326 is the SRID here.)

For GeoDjango, your model will be defined like this:

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models
class Thing(models.Model):
    # ...
    location = models.PointField(srid=4326)  
    objects = models.GeoManager()
```

If you're actually using 4326, you can leave it out, as that's the default.
Then, you'll set the `location` of your model instances so:

```
from django.contrib.gis.geos import Point
some_thing.location = Point(-122, 37)
```

Comment: Maybe that's part of my issue -- I don't know what a SRID even maps to, so I'm not sure which one I need to use. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Sweet, your syntax worked like a charm. 4326 seems to be the ticket. For others who are lost like I was, this thread has good insights on what SRIDs are: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/373589/geometry-column-stgeomfromtext-and-srid-what-is-an-srid

Thanks!